# Counting instances in a column

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have the following table

```
mykey.mytable

id | user   | item
------------------
 0 | 'matt' | 'ball'
 1 | 'bob'  | 'bat'
 2 | 'bill' | 'fridge'
 3 | 'matt' | 'beer'
```

What I would like is a count of users, for example

```
user   | count
--------------
'matt' | 2
'bob'  | 1
'bill' | 1
```

How do I do this in Cassandra?

FWIW, I have experimented with count(*), batch, counter and using the result of one select in another. Documentation is not much help and my google foo is failing to find any examples. I'm getting a little frustrated!

Comment: In what way is the documentation "not much help". Do you have any knoeledge of SQL?

Comment: @Raedwald CQL is a subset of SQL.  So knowledge of SQL won't help much here.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 It helps with the basics, such as what a `SELECT` is.

Comment: @Raewald my knowledge of SQL and RDBMS is proving more of a problem. Getting this info from a RDB is straight forward. I didn't expect to have to spend 5 hours to decypher Cassandra's CQL implementation. All good though, thanks to BryceAtNetwork23 I am moving again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Cassandra CQL does not have an aggregation framework.  So while you could easily do this in a relational database with a `GROUP BY` and a `COUNT`, Cassandra has no such mechanism.

One of the main principles of non-relational (NoSQL) data modeling, is to build your tables to match your query patterns.  If querying the number of user items is something you forsee needing to do, then you could create another table to hold that information:

```
CREATE TABLE userItemCount (
user text,
itemCount counter,
PRIMARY KEY (user)
);
```

Via CQL you could increment that counter like this (assuming that Matt gets another item):

```
UPDATE userItemCount SET itemCount=itemCount+1 WHERE user='matt';
```

Of course, the down-side of this, is that you'll need to build a mechanism to add/increment the appropriate data when an entry is stored in your original table.

For a video walk through on this and other Cassandra development concepts, check out the free Java/Cassandra class on Datastax Academy: https://datastaxacademy.elogiclearning.com.  Session #2, Module 43 covers the use of "counter tables."

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I need. Do you know of an online tutorial that covers this and other practical implementation stuff? I have theory coming out my ears, but cannot find a walk through or examples.

Comment: @MattStevens edit made to include a reference to a video module in DataStax Academy's "Java Development with Apache Cassandra" class.